# Is an orthogonal-increment process submartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

If I remember correctly, a stochastic process is said to be orthogonal-increment, if it is a second-order process, and the increments over disjoint intervals are uncorrelated.

I wonder if an orthogonal-increment process is a submartingale? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, at least not in the time-discrete case:

Let $(\xi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ identically distributed independent random variables such that $\xi_j \in L^2$, $\mathbb{E}\xi_j < 0$. Define a (time-discrete) process $M_n$ bei $$M_n := \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j$$
Then $(M_n)_n$ has orthogonal increments (in the sense of your definition), but it's not a submartingale since $$\mathbb{E}M_n = n \cdot \mathbb{E}\xi_1$$ is decreasing in $n$.

Comment: How are those increments orthogonal?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland That's why I wrote that the increments are orthogonal in the sense of the definition the OP gave. The increments are uncorrelated since they are independent. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I thought that the OP meant orthogonal in $L^2$, but I see now that I am wrong. Apologies!

Comment: That, or any deterministic function.